# Concentration probabilities for distributions with $\exp(-c t^\alpha)$ tails

Tags: probability, probability-theory, concentration-of-measure

I am trying to generalize the concentration inequalities for the sub-exponential and sub-gaussian distributions to a larger family with tail $\exp(-c t^\alpha)$ for arbitrary $\alpha > 0$. In particular, we have the Hoeffding inequality for sub-gaussian distributions (corresponding to $\alpha = 2$) and the Bernstein inequality for the sub-exponential distributions (corresponding to $\alpha = 1$). However, both the proofs I have read heavily rely on the specific $\alpha$ values and are hard to generalize. Is there any way to generalize these inequalities to arbitrary $\alpha > 0$?

Comment: Yes it is possible. For example see exercise 2.7.3. of Roman Vershynin's "High Dimensional Probability". The proof of Proposition 2.7.1. should work with very minor modifications.

Comment: It is not actually clear what you want to prove. You are assuming a tail bound and you want to prove another tail bound?